# Is there any simple way to format decimals in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I know it could be done trivially in a non-SQL environment [post-data processing, frontend, what have you], but that's not possible at the moment. Is there a way to take a `decimal(5,2)` and convert it to a `varchar` without the trailing zeroes/decimal points? For example:

```
declare @number decimal(5,2)
set @number = 123.00
select cast(@number as varchar) as FormattedNumber
```

And the result is '123.00'. Is there a (simple) way to get '123' instead? And likewise, instead of '123.30', '123.3'? Could do it by figuring out whether or not the hundredths/tenths places were 0 and manually trimming characters, but I wanted to know if there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: I would return the data as-is from the database, and leave the formatting down to the front-end. Is there a reason why you can't do this?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it's not really an option - the frontend, as it stands, is too generalized to have special cases of formatting specific fields being return (as the number of columns etc may change), and no other column needs to be formatted, so the simplest thing I see is to just do it from SQL.

Comment: With SQL Server 2012+ You can use the FORMAT() function. You would use '#,##' or '#,##.0' as your second param. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@number AS float) AS varchar(10))
```

However you may want to test this carefully with your raw data first.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was something this simple.

Answer (score 4):

This way is pretty simple:

```
DECLARE @Number DECIMAL(5,2)

SELECT @Number = 123.65

SELECT FormattedNumber = CAST(CAST(@Number AS DECIMAL(3,0)) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

Returns '124'.

The only thing to consider is whether you want to round up/down, or just strip the zeroes and decimal points without rounding; you'd cast the DECIMAL as an INT in the second case.

Answer (score 3):

For controlled formatting of numbers in T-SQL you should use the `FORMAT()` function. For example:

```
DECLARE @number DECIMAL(9,2); SET @number = 1234567.12;
DECLARE @formatted VARCHAR(MAX); SET @formatted = FORMAT(@number, 'N0', 'en-AU');
PRINT @formatted;
```

The result will be:

```
1,234,567
```

The arguments to the `FORMAT()` function are:

```
FORMAT(value, format [, culture])
```

The value argument is your number. The format argument is a CLR type formatting string (in this example, I specified "normal number, zero precision"). The optional culture argument allows you to override the server culture setting to format the number as per a desired culture.

See also [the MSDN ref page for `FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The Convert function may do what you want to do.

```
ms-help://MS.SQLCC.v9/MS.SQLSVR.v9.en/tsqlref9/html/a87d0850-c670-4720-9ad5-6f5a22343ea8.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this again....

```
CREATE FUNCTION saneDecimal(@input decimal(5,2)) returns varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @output varchar(10)
SET @output = CAST(@input AS varchar(10))

DECLARE @trimmable table (trimval char(1))
INSERT @trimmable VALUES ('0')
INSERT @trimmable VALUES ('.')

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @trimmable WHERE trimval = CAST(SUBSTRING(@output, LEN(@output), 1) AS char(1)))
    SET @output = LEFT(@output, LEN(@output) - 1)

RETURN @output
END

GO

SELECT dbo.saneDecimal(1.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the trailing zeroes in a while loop:

```
declare @number decimal(5,2)
declare @str varchar(100)
set @number = 123.00
set @str = @number
while substring(@str,len(@str),1) in ('0','.',',')
    set @str = substring(@str,1,len(@str)-1)
```

But as AdaTheDev commented, this is more easily done client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and elegant? Not so much...but that's T-SQL for you:

```
DECLARE @number decimal(5,2) = 123.00
DECLARE @formatted varchar(5) = CAST(@number as varchar)

SELECT 
    LEFT(
        @formatted,
        LEN(@formatted)
            - PATINDEX('%[^0.]%', REVERSE(@formatted)) 
            + 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Format(value,format string,culture) function in SQL Server 2012+

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or Greater you can use the format function like this:

```
select format(@number,'0') as FormattedNumber
```

Of course the format function will return an nvarchar, and not a varchar. You can cast to get a specific type.

Answer (score -2):

Also, take a look at the T-SQL STR function in Books Online; this can be used for formatting floats and might work for your case.  For some reason it doesn't come up in Google searches relating to this problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. Please check the accepted answer for this question.